# Netbeans 8.0.1 with Java 8u25 on Mac OS X Yosemite retina BLURRY

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, retina-display, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded the Mac OS, the older Netbeans 7.3 started firing errors. After upgrading both Java and Netbeans to latest versions, everything works except Netbeans seems blurry. I had this error before but now it is supposed to be resolved with the latest version of both. Not sure what is going on. I'm including the versions here:

`Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 (Build 201408251540)
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0.1 Patch 1.1
Java: 1.7.0_17; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.7-b01
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_17-b02
System: Mac OS X version 10.10 running on x86_64; UTF-8; en_US (nb)`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to install JDK 8u25 for mac. The JRE is not enough to run Netbeans, so it essentially was using the old JRE which did not support retina well.

Here is the link: [JDK 8u25 Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)

The way to test if you have the right version is by running this in the command line:

```
java -version
```

You should see this back:

```
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```